# Regex Split in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a text that has many questions and each question has a seperator `QId` {QuestionId}.

Now I want to split this text with `QId` {QuestionId} to get a dictionary with keys as {QuestionId} and the question body as a Value. Here `questionId` is dynamic will have any Integer value.

I have tried this `Regex.Split` with regex `"\\s*QId\\s*[\\d]+\\s*\\s*"`.
I can get the question body but I want Question Id, too, as a Key so I can do some action based on QuestionId.

[image]

I have tried below code:

```
Regex.Split(
    text, string.Format("\\s*{0}\\s*[\\d]+\\s*\\s*",
    "QID"), RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

It did not give me data in dictionary.

Comment: Maybe `Regex.Split(htmlContent, @"\s*(QID\s*\d+)\s*")` will do?

Comment: Do question IDs repeat? Or are they unique?

Comment: _"**html**Content"_ - Mhmmm....

Comment: You're input is multi-line but you explicitly pass Singleline. Why?

Comment: Also show us the html, not an image of it. How do you get new lines in it? Is it, for example, with `<BR>`?

Comment: @tymtam `RegexOptions.Singleline` is redundant here, OP does not understand what it does, but it is not critical. Actually, `RegexOptions.Singleline` is a good idea if the match spans across several lines, but it only affects the `.` pattern, and there is no `.` in this pattern.

Comment: Do not use Regex. Use Html Tools.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew {QuestionId} is dynamic and will be unique

Answer (score -1):

Your input does *not* look like this:

```
QID 1 
Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?

QID 2 
What time is it?

QID 3 
In what time zone?
```

It's more something like this:

```html
<p><B>QID 1</B><BR>Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?</p>
<p><B>QID 2</B><BR>What time is it?</p>
<p><B>QID 3</B><BR>  In what time zone?</p>
```

This means that you will have to take the html tags into consideration and `\s` (whitespace) will not be enough.

---

Html and regex don't mix well and you may want to consider using  a html library or some other way (maybe `string.Split`). Please see, [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and its legendary answer.